# Is it possible to ensure that strings encrypted with AES128/CBC/PKCS5Padding never have trailing equals characters

Tags: encryption, cryptography, language-agnostic

Is there a deterministic way to ensure that any encrypted/encoded String created with AES128/CBC/PKCS5Padding never has '=' characters padding the end?

Given a crypto util which is a black-box:

```
String originalValue = "this is a test";
String encryptedValue = TheCryptoUtil.encrypt(original);
```

The encryptedValue will often look like:

```
R2gDfGwGvkqZWHH4UF81rg==
```

Is there a way of varying "originalValue" e.g. by padding the input with whitespaces, such that, regardless of the keys used by TheCryptoUtil, the output will not have any "=" at the end?

Comment: This is a perfect example of an X Y problem...  Tell us about the problem you are trying to solve, not what you think will solve the problem.

Comment: I will clarify :)

Comment: I think you misunderstood.  Why do you want to do this?  Yes, what you want to do is possible, but it is likely far easier to solve the original problem that you are having.  So again, why do you want to do this?

Comment: I'm not going to explain it in detail except to say that that I've seen it done and I want to know how. E.g. there is a system that emits encrypted tokens that we decrypt with AES128/CBC/PKCS5Padding and yet the encoded tokens it emits never are padded. I want to know how its doing it :-). The only theory I have is that it is somehow padding the originalValue such that the results never have the = characters

Comment: Just remove the padding. It is not necessary for almost all implementations I've seen. As long as you have a way to know when the cyphertext ends removing the padding is completely harmless. The system you saw probably simply removed the padding without doing anything fancy

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.  I have no idea why you want to do this, but it is possible.  Things to keep in mind:

- The output of AES-128 with PKCS5Padding will always be some multiple of 16.  That is, `len(ciphertext) % 16 == 0`.
- The equals signs that you see on the end of the ciphertext have nothing to do with AES.  They are actually base64 padding.
- Base64 takes, as input, blocks of 3 bytes and converts them into blocks of 4 characters, where these output 4 characters are any of the 64 defined characters.

This means that the number of bytes of output determines whether or not the base64 of the output will have padding.  For example, if you encrypt the message `The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.`, I'd say it is fairly likely (depending on your "black box encryption") that the result will not have any base64 padding.

So, the fact that base64 always produces an encoded string of length that is divisible by 4 means that we can easily determine that length of the original with or without padding.  In fact, base64 padding is only part of the spec to help with concatenation issues.

I expect you'll be able to figure out the rest from here!

Answer (score 0):

Luke's answer is correct to say that AES has nothing to do with the padding, it is however missing some of the information below.

Base 64 usually produces padding if the *input* is not dividable by 3. The padding is just there to make sure that the output only consists of blocks of 4 characters from the base 64 alphabet. Base 64 encodes 64 values or 6 bits per character. 3 bytes are 24 bits, which is dividable by 6 giving you 4 characters required.

---

The naive thing to do would be to adjust the AES output so that it is dividable by 3. This can however require up to 34 additional padding bytes on the input of AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding, which is stupidity at best.

Not all base 64 schemes actually use padding, so the easiest way of accomplishing this is simply to select a base 64 scheme that doesn't perform the padding at all. Java for instance has a [`withoutPadding()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html#withoutPadding--) configuration method.

If the base 64 encoder cannot handle that then it is possible to simply remove the padding after it has been generated. Before decoding you can add back one or two `'='` characters until you count a number of base 64 characters (excluding whitespace, see notes) that is dividable by 4.

---

Note that base 64 usually also uses `/` and `+` in the alphabet (there are only 2 * 26 + 10 = 62 characters if you use upper-/lowercase chars & digits). You could look up a URL-safe base 64 encoding - called **base64url** - if that is what you are after.

Base64 for MIME may also use spaces and end-of-line characters, by the way.